# margin-left:auto cannot be negative, but margin-right:auto can

Tags: css, margin

The following situation:
http://files.dqxtech.net/leftmargin/
http://jsfiddle.net/xeFN3/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element-left">
  </div>
  <div class="element-right">
  </div>
</div>
```

with

```
.container {
  width:120px;
}
.element-left {
  width:120px;
  margin-left:12%:
  margin-right:auto;
}
.element-right {
  width:120px;
  margin-right:12%:
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

Problem:
The .element-left should be positioned symmetrical to the .element-right, but it is not.
For .element-left, the "auto" margin evaluates to something negative, and the "12%" margin evaluates to exactly 12%.
For .element-right, the "auto" margin evaluates to zero, and the "12%" margin evaluates to something negative.

Any idea why this happens, and how to fix it?
text-align does make any difference.

Comment: I realize, I could float the elements as a possible solution. But this does not really explain the asymmetric behavior.

Comment: And, I should mention, I tried this stuff with Chromium, Firefox and Opera on Ubuntu.

Comment: I could also make the container bigger, but then the 12% would make a different result in px.

Comment: could you replicate the same effect here please?
http://jsfiddle.net/Tjewq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `margin`-value `auto` always evaluates to zero or a positive pixel count.

> For .element-left, the "auto" margin evaluates to something negative

No, the `margin-right` evaluates to zero; the element just overflow its parent, which can be controlled by the `overflow` property. Elements by default overflow to the right and bottom. This behavior can be reversed by setting the text direction from `ltr` to `rtl` (right to left).

I guess, you'll be better off using relative positions for both the inner `DIV`'s.
Another possible solution is to [use fixed negative value instead of `auto` (e.g. `-12%`)](http://jsfiddle.net/xeFN3/2/).

Comment: ok, the rtl / ltr explains the asymmetric behavior! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm. The two solutions you mentioned do not exactly achieve the intended result. I want 12% margin-right both in "narrow" and in "narrowest" container. This means, there is no reliable value for margin-left. And the position relative does not cut it either.  

I think direction:rtl; would actually do what I want. It just feels a bit dirty to me, using it for this purpose.

Comment: "It just feels a bit dirty […]" It is!

Comment: what gets damaged by the dirt?

Comment: The hint for rtl/ltr was the kind of information I needed. Someone reminded me to accept answers to my questions, so here you are :)